# Monk half diminished

Tags: theory

In Thelonious Monk’s “Ugly Beauty” why does monk voice the first chord D-7b5 with a natural 5 (A) in bass instead of Ab or another chord tone

Comment: Sounds to me the 1st and 3rd are not really part of the chord, but merely a note played *before* the chord certainly not pedalled through. In the recording I listened to, the 2nd has what I consider a fluffed note.

Comment: Source? What recording, time? The one I found starts with the notes, in ascending order: D A Ab C D E G, with D being the lowest note. And not all of them are held down.

Comment: The first chord harmonized with a melody note is D-7b5 with A natural in bass a fifth above D on his album underground. I was curious why he chose this voicing

Comment: This one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuoIJA7_Tm0 The first note is D.

Comment: Yeah at 0:10 he hits the first chord

Comment: It's a D in the bass, I don't understand what you're talking about. Lowest four notes: D - A - Ab - C. The A adds dissonance to it. Try it by lowering the A to Ab, it's a lot more boring and the beauty is not ugly anymore. Athanasius explained it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that we can say precisely why a choice was made to voice the chord this way without some actual commentary from Monk himself.  (And that's unlikely to be found.)

However, there is a consistency of harmony and one might even say "motive" in this piece surrounding the use of major sevenths and minor seconds at key moments.

The chord isn't really a typical Dm7♭5.  The [first sheet](https://theloniousspheremonk.weebly.com/uploads/1/5/3/6/15366006/ugly_beauty.pdf) I was able to pull up for it in fact carries a special footnote about the voicing and the fact that this chord contains both A and A♭ in quite a few occurrences.  So, the question's assumption that A♮ isn't a chord tone is incorrect, I think.  In this piece, it *is* a chord tone.

And, as I said, this isn't the only place that this kind of more striking dissonance occurs -- not necessarily in that particular voicing, but the major seventh/minor second aspect is strong in the harmonic language here, and in more pronounced ways than the typical uses of maj7 chords in jazz.

Moreover, there's a kind of V-I sensation created by the initial two chords (Dm7-G7), and the D-A bass voicing makes for a stronger harmonic resolution with that open fifth.  To me, I think it's best to think of this particular chord as a Dm7 with the added ♭5.  That ♭5 will become the ♭9 of the next chord, but it ultimately plants the seed for the fact that eventually we will modulate to D♭.  The A♭ is thus a bit of "color" in the opening chords that initially needs an explanation.  Many composers like to create a sort of opening gambit that gradually reveals the harmonic world -- at the outside, we're not sure what to do with this highly dissonant chord, but the note that "doesn't fit" will be the springboard (dominant) to where we're going to finally resolve.  This opening chord is therefore a signal of harmonic uncertainty, of a clash between emerging potential keys.

That's just one potential interpretation.  But -- bottom line is that it sets up the character of the harmonic world of the piece.

Answer (score 0):

Athanasius explained the A note and the whole thing well. They are in some way "wrong" notes, bringing something from a slightly "conflicting" idea. You could call that dissonance, but in my opinion the D-A fifth creates a simultaneous alternative harmonic interpretation in addition to a simple Dm7-5 - G7 - Cm. But sometimes the best way to "analyze" it is to try and change it, so let's construct a counter-example. What if the wrong notes weren't there?